# cron expression Every minute starting at specific time

Tags: cron

I would like to run a cron expression Every minute starting at 2 PM

How can I achieve this?

Any suggestions please

Comment: What cron flavour? You're getting answers for Quartz, which is different from old school cron (6 instead of 5 parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want it for that hour-
0 0/1 2 ? * * *

You may find this site helpful.
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting at 2pm (14:00) but ending when?
Assuming you want to end running at 16:00 (4pm):

```
0 * 14-16 ? * *
```